# Is FireBear Improved Import Export Extension/Support Safe?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, database, migration

I purchased the FireBear Improved Import Export Extension with support so that I can merge two stores into one and upgrade from Magento 1 to Magento 2.

After downloading the plugins and contacting their support through a ticket system on Bitbucket someone named Mr. Jack is requesting SSH access to the servers and an administrator account.

Being that this is an international company that I can't find a lot of info on I wanted to check and see if anyone has had experience with them and knows if they are reputable/safe enough to give access to my database.

Answer (score 0):

I also bought the FireBear Improved Import Export Extension and it's enhancing the Magento 2 default products import. So it can be helpful if you plan importing products/customers/orders in your Magento 2 store, let's say based on CSV. But I think the tool is helpful if you have already the data from a different language/technology based platform and you want to import.

But if you are migrating intra-technology (from Magento 1 to Magento 2) I would recommend using the official Magento tools for Data Migration:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/migration/bk-migration-guide.html

Concerning the SSH access, you should first check your company policy and see if providing access to a 3rd party vendor is allowed. Then, concerning the trust, I think the opinions are really split: some really trustable companies or websites might be a scam and some really not trustable companies with a poor presentation website might turn in the end to be correct. As far as I know about these guys, they are from Germany, so more details on their website. But in my opinion, you should listen first to your company policy. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I believe I will try to use the plugin and just ask them lots of questions about the process. If for some reason I can't get it to work then I will just replace user data with some dummy data and let them connect to an isolated development box. Then once they have the scripts setup I can lock them out and run them on the actual production data. Do you know of what tables if any contain credit card info? I am working with a database dump so I know it is Magento 1.X but I am not sure on the specific version that the dump was for.